# String is being printed to console twice

Tags: java

Every time I run the code it, and I get to the part where it asks the user for an input it prints "action: " twice but only on the first iteration of the while loop. After that first iteration the code runs fine. Should I use StringBuffer?

```
package edu.collin.cocs2436.chocolatebox;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChocolateBoxDemo implements ISize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ChocolateBox box = null;
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Enter the size of the box: ");
                    int size = input.nextInt();
                    box = new ChocolateBox(size);
                    break;
                } catch (InvalidSizeException ise) {
                    System.out.println(ise);
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("action: ");
                String action = input.nextLine();

                String[] userDecision = action.split(" ", 2);
                if (userDecision[0].equals("done"))
                    break;
                try {
                    switch (userDecision[0]) {
                    case "putTruffle":
                        box.putChocolateInBox(new Truffle(userDecision[1]));
                        break;
                    case "putPraline":
                        box.putChocolateInBox(new Praline(userDecision[1]));
                        break;
                    case "putGanache":
                        box.putChocolateInBox(new Ganache(userDecision[1]));
                        break;
                    case "remove":
                        box.removeLastChocolate();
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

the output looks something like this

```
Enter the size of the box: 5
action: action: putTruffle Vanilla
added Vanilla Truffle
action: remove
removed Vanilla Truffle
action:
```